# Snakemake: MissingOutputException when output does exist

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm trying to make a snakemake pipeline and it complains about a MissingOutputException:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 8
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       add_replace_readgroups
        1       all
        1       annotate_nirvana
        1       apply_bqsr
        1       base_recalibrator
        1       bwa_aln1
        1       bwa_aln2
        1       bwa_sampe
        1       flagstats
        1       haplotypecaller
        1       intervals
        1       isize
        1       json2vcf
        1       mark_dups
        1       mod_sam
        1       region_coverage
        1       sam2bam
        17

[Wed Jul 17 09:03:04 2019]
rule bwa_aln2:
    input: C052007W-B.2.fq.gz, /mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/PKD_GANAB/PKD.fasta
    output: tmp/C052007W-B.2.sai
    log: logs/bwa_aln2/C052007W-B.log
    jobid: 8
    wildcards: sample=C052007W-B
    threads: 8

bwa aln -t 8 -q 15 -e 50 -f tmp/C052007W-B.2.sai /mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/PKD_GANAB/PKD.fasta C052007W-B.2.fq.gz 2> logs/bwa_aln2/C052007W-B.log
Submitted job 8 with external jobid 'Submitted batch job 283790'.

[Wed Jul 17 09:03:04 2019]
rule bwa_aln1:
    input: C052007W-B.1.fq.gz, /mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/PKD_GANAB/PKD.fasta
    output: tmp/C052007W-B.1.sai
    log: logs/bwa_aln1/C052007W-B.log
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: sample=C052007W-B
    threads: 8

bwa aln -t 8 -q 15 -e 50 -f tmp/C052007W-B.1.sai /mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/PKD_GANAB/PKD.fasta C052007W-B.1.fq.gz 2> logs/bwa_aln1/C052007W-B.log
Submitted job 7 with external jobid 'Submitted batch job 283791'.
Waiting at most 30 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 63 of /mnt/storage/home/kimy/projects/automate_CP/scripts/Snakefile:
Missing files after 30 seconds:
tmp/C052007W-B.2.sai
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Waiting at most 30 seconds for missing files.
[Wed Jul 17 09:04:04 2019]
Finished job 7.
1 of 17 steps (6%) done
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /mnt/storage/home/kimy/projects/automate_CP/CP0340/.snakemake/log/2019-07-17T090304.049684.snakemake.log
```

I'm running this using this command line:

```
/mnt/storage/home/kimy/software/miniconda3/bin/snakemake \
    -s /mnt/storage/home/kimy/projects/automate_CP/scripts/Snakefile \
    -j 8 \
    -p \
    --latency-wait 30 \
    --configfile ./${sample}_config.yaml \
    --cluster "sbatch --job-name=NILES --ntasks=1 --partition=long --time=12:00:00 --mem=25000 --reservation=compute006"
```

However the files that Snakemake complains about do exist and if I rerun the same snakefile, the next rule is run but it complains about the output of that next rule.
Another detail: I ran the pipeline for a whole folder (where I have a bunch of fastqs and using another config file of course) and it worked fine for every sample except for 2 of them, prompting me to investigate the sample.

Do you know why I get this error?

Comment: The error occurs when the command i.e bwa completes but the output file is not created. You should usually be able to trace the cause in the log file i.e `logs/bwa_aln2/C052007W-B.log`. Does the log file indicate anything wrong with the bwa run?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, `11644 sequences have been processed` etc.. And as I said, the output files have been created and they're not empty.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, it worked for most samples in a folder, but not 2 of them, and it consistently fails on those 2?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when running snakemake on a cluster is that the main snakemake job is the one checking that the output files exist, not the job that created the file. These jobs could be running on separate nodes, which means it might take some time for the networked file system to sync. You might just need to increase the latency-wait parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Colin, you were correct. 2 samples failed consistently and increasing the latency-wait parameter fixed the issue. I had previously increased it to 30 seconds but it seems it wasn't enough. 60 seconds fixed the issue.